# Code rewrite - MemoryError

Tags: python, csv, numpy

I am writing a python script to read two csv files. Code snippet is available below. The code works perfectly, if files contain few records (8,000) however I encountered MemoryError on line (`X_train = X_train.astype('float32')`) if file contain large number of records (120,000).

```
img_lst_train = []
label_lst_train = []

img_lst_test = []
label_lst_test = []

print ('Reading training file')

with open('train.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in readCSV:
        img = cv2.imread(row[0])
        img_lst_train.append(img) 
        label_lst_train.append(row[1])

print ('Reading testing file')

with open('val.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in readCSV:
        img = cv2.imread(row[0])
        img_lst_test.append(img) 
        label_lst_test.append(row[1])



img_lst_train = np.array(img_lst_train)
label_lst_train = np.array(label_lst_train)
img_lst_test = np.array(img_lst_test)
label_lst_test = np.array(label_lst_test)


X_train = img_lst_train
y_train = label_lst_train
X_test  = img_lst_test
y_test  = label_lst_test

# Convert class vectors to binary class matrices.
Y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, nb_classes)
Y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, nb_classes)


X_train = X_train.astype('float32')
X_test = X_test.astype('float32')
```

Structure of train.csv and val.csv

```
path to image file, label
path to image file, label
path to image file, label
.........................
```

How I can rewrite the above code to avoid MemoryError

Comment: what is the size of your csv files?

Comment: the size of `train.csv` file is `10.8` MB @AkshayNevrekar

Comment: One thing that you could do that completely eliminates all memory issues is to read the files [lazily](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators). But that depends on how you intend to use the data afterwards, so, what do you do once you read them? Feed them to a model? If yes, which one?

Comment: yes, I am feeding data to a resnet network. @ArneRecknagel

Comment: which library exactly?

Comment: I am using keras with tensorflow at backend. @ArneRecknagel

Comment: Then you can't use lazy generation, Keras' `train` only takes numpy arrays.

Comment: One tip for the future, if you tag questions of yours that include numpy functions with the `numpy` tag, you have a much higher chance to get an answer sooner. =)

Comment: thank you for the tip. @ArneRecknagel

Comment: @cswah You are welcome. Did the answer work?

Comment: @cswah, how much RAM do you have? Also, do you know the structure of the files, will a sparse array work here? Last, you can try training the 8000 files in lower precision (float16), and if the performance difference is reasonable, use it for the larger dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numpy's [`astype`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html#numpy-ndarray-astype) function supports a parameter `copy` that, if set to false, will work on the initial array instead of generating a copy. In code:

```
X_train = X_train.astype('float32', copy=False)
X_test = X_test.astype('float32', copy=False)
```

If you still run out of memory at some point, you can also read your train, validation, and test sets sequentially instead of at the same time. Once converted to float, the arrays take up less space, and that could make the difference.

Comment: Well, then I'm afraid you either need more RAM or a better numpy expert to help you =/